# How to plot positive and Negative Bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly, bar-chart

I have a dataset named pct below

I want to have positive and negative bar charts using ggplot2 or plotly package.

given the dataset in the table below

| Month | pct |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 45% |
| Feb-20 | 34% |
| Mar-20 | -15% |
| Apr-20 | -11% |
| May-20 | 17% |
| Jun-20 | 15% |
| Jul-20 | 45% |
| Aug-20 | 17% |
| Sep-20 | -11% |
| Oct-20 | -21% |
| Nov-20 | 74% |
| Dec-20 | 12% |

I want to get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- a trace for positive values and a trace for negative values
- use **textformat** for labels above / below bars

Built before I saw this was R.  Approach to building **plotly** figure is the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """Month,pct
Jan-20,45%
Feb-20,34%
Mar-20,-15%
Apr-20,-11%
May-20,17%
Jun-20,15%
Jul-20,45%
Aug-20,17%
Sep-20,-11%
Oct-20,-21%
Nov-20,74%
Dec-20,12%"""
    )
)

df["pct"] = pd.to_numeric(df["pct"].str[:-1]) / 100
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime("01-" + df["Month"])

px.bar(
    df,
    x="Month",
    y="pct",
    color=df["pct"] > 0,
    color_discrete_map={True: "green", False: "red"},
    text_auto=True
).update_layout(yaxis={"tickformat": "3.0%"},  xaxis_dtick="M1", showlegend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but why is the monthly not fully displaying for example Jan skipped Feb then march skipped April then may 
is there a way all the month would fully display

Comment: updated answer, just use of **dtick** on xaxis

Comment: was this written in python 
i want the answer written in R

Comment: yes - hence comment *Built before I saw this was R. Approach to building plotly figure is the same*  I don't have a working R env at moment, plotly concepts are fully transportable across python, R and javascript